# Swift: UILabel MultiLine

Tags: swift, uilabel

I'm got a little problem with my `UILabel`. Below the picture :
[image]

This is my snippet code :

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: (0), width: 350, height: 80))
    label.center = CGPoint(x: (view.frame.size.width / 2), y: (view.frame.size.height / 2) )
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 35)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.text = "Total\n\(dataOverview["totClean"])"
```

I want to make the label become  :

`Total
  95`

I have been add `label.numberOfLines` and `Total\n...` but still not work. Do i do a mistake? Thanks in Advance

Solved with great answer and suggest below. Here my label now :

[image]

Comment: Do you have any constraints set on the label?

Comment: Just increase the `UILabel` height to `150`

Comment: ^^you could either do this or not use a fixed font size, but the above should work just fine.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon no its still doesnt work. Before i think the height is not enough but i wrong

Comment: Have you tried `label.sizeToFit()` ?

Comment: @moni15 make it as answer, its work thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `label.sizeToFit()` to the end of this

Comment: I don't think it's a good solution in a long run - assuming you translate your app to different language or number becomes like 10000 ?
Then UILabel will become huuuuuuge and may overlap with your circle.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski I mean that is all situational.. There are a thousand ways to approach a problem. If those are the factors someone is dealing with then I would think there would be a hell of a lot more precautions should be considered... like hard coding your label text..? or hard coding an escape sequence... I think you're just big on being right :)

Comment: Well I strongly disagree - sizeToFit() should not be used in this case when UILabel overlaps with another view and it can cover it.
It is ok when you size UITableViewCell for example and you want it to grow, but definitely not here.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase frame size to 120 as 80 is not enough for your font size:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0 y: 0, width: 350, height: 120))
```

Alternatively a better solution in my opinion will be to do this:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: (50), width: 350, height: 80))
    label.center = CGPoint(x: (view.frame.size.width / 2), y: (view.frame.size.height / 2) )
label.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 35)
label.textAlignment = .center
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.text = "Total\n95)"
//make a font scaling to fit text inside label
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
```

With that approach you can size your label to fill inside of a circle and make sure it will not overlap it.

Assuming you will do translations to your application or just number becomes big enough, the UILabel will continue to grow.
Just changing the size of UILabel forever is never a good solution, neither is `label.sizeToFit()` as it result in problems like here:

[image]

Comparing to sizing the textfield well to fit center of circle:

Comment: `label.sizeToFit` work for me without change the heights label. I try this and its works too but i need some custom label inside there so height 80 its enough for me. Thanks +1 as work answer

Comment: @MarioMargoPradipta I would really advice to go with decreasing size font approach - just as a better solution in long run that will prevent UILabel from overlapping the cricle and going out of control.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I decrease the width into 80. I Will edited my picture. Thanks in advance